# Why is this taking a product of two specific functions sufficient to prove no other solutions exist for this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In Hirsch, Smale, and Devaney, we are introduced to the differential equation $x'(t) = ax(t)$ and they prove that the only solution to the differential equation is $x(t)=ke^{at}.$

Why is it sufficient to prove that this is the only solution by the following calculations?

> Let $u(t)$ be any solution.
> $\frac{d}{dt}(u(t)e^{-at}) = u'(t)e^{-at} + u(t)(-ae^{-at}) $
> $= au(t)e^{-at} - au(t)e^{-at} = 0$

Comment: The map $y(t) = u(t)e^{-at}$ satisfies $y'=0$.
Therefore, there exists a constant $k\in \Bbb R$ such that $\forall t, y(t) = k$, and the result follows.

Comment: Oh, and every other solution $u(t) = ke^{at}$!

Comment: @Didier What is the motivation behind using $y(t)$? Why are we considering solutions of an equation multiplied by $e^{-at}$? Only because it gets us what we want?

Comment: If we already know a solution, a common "trick" is to subtract out that solution, and show that the resulting difference satisfies an equation that we know only has zero as the solution. This is more or less the same trick, but with division instead of subtraction, and the equation we know (i e. derivative equals zero) has as its solutions only constant functions.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how historically this happened. But here is my point of view: we already know that $e^{at}$ is a solution (that is, in some sense, the reason the exponential map exists). From there, we know that any constant multiple of that function is also a solution. But we can't find any other solution by hand. This might suggest that there is no other solution. If this intuition is right, this reduces to show that $u(t)e^{-at}$ is constant. And we know how to characterize constant functions: their derivatives identically vanish

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it finally makes sense.

Comment: The trick applies to more general solutions. Next level: Try and simplify $\frac d{dx}(u(x)e^{f(x)})=0$. Reformukate this in the form “The solutions of the DE … are precisely the functions of the form $u(x)=\ldots$”

Comment: @Didier: That's an answer, no?